# How to transform a .csv string list representation to list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, data-structures

Suppose a `.csv` file which looks like this:

- title: is the name of the column
- and `[senior innovation manager]` is the first row.

Note: both strings (title and row) look exactly as written here.

```
title    
[senior innovation manager]
```

The idea is to convert this list string representation to an actual python list:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read the file
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=',', na_values='NA', encoding='latin-1')

# convert first row to actual python list
df['title'][0]=ast.literal_eval(df['title'][0])

# inspect if ast.literal_eval() converted to actual list:
print(df['title'][0])
print(type(df['title'][0]))
```

However when tried the above code the next error arises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_path", line 76, in <module>        
    df['title'][0]=ast.literal_eval(df['title'][0])
  File "C:\Users\id\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Users\id\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [senior innovation manager]
```

What's the nature of this error?

Is it possible to convert this list string representation
to an actual python list?

Comment: `[senior innovation manager]` is not a valid Python literal. Why do you think this _should_ work?

Comment: Because it looks like a list

Comment: you need to put comma between the items of the list @AlvaroMartinez
```ast.literal_eval(df['title'][0].replace(" ",','))```

Comment: In your example, that column is `"# title    "`, not `"title"` as your code shows. And the column value is `"# [senior innovation manager]"`. `# [senior innovation manager]` isn't valid python, so `ast` isn't the tool to use. From your example, you could just strip the angle brackets and make a list as in `[df['title'][0][3:-1]]`.

Comment: And you would need quotes around it

Comment: Are you sure the data is exactly as you show? Its a 2 line file and both lines start with "# "? The list on the second line... can there be multiple values in the list? If so, how are they separated?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @tdelaney, yeah # should not be there...

Comment: @tdelaney, it's a comma sepated values excel-based file

Comment: It might look like a Python list if it was `[ "senior", "innovation", "manager" ]` or `[ "senior innovation manager" ]`, but without the quotes it doesn't look like a valid Python list at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any advantage to treating this as a CSV file or using pandas. You could simply read the second line of the file and strip the unwanted stuff out. You can do that by grabbing a slice from the second character to one before the end. In python list syntax, that's `1:-1`.

```
with open(file_path) as fileobj:
    # skip title
    fileobj.readline()
    # get data
    title_list = [fileobj.readline().strip()[1:-1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `literal_eval` your string must be written exactly as it would written in code. That is the string values contained in your list must be in quotes and separated by a comma. So your string should look something like this `['senior', 'innovation', 'manager']`
If you're set on using this method you could try replacing the spaces in your string by `', '` and then adding the last two quotes after opening and before closing the brackets.